# "Ensurance" isn't a word, so what can I use instead?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a word that means exactly "The action of ensuring something."

Example sentences (with the coined word *ensurance*):

*"The neophyte may claim competence at the task, but your ensurance of its completion would ease my mind."*

*"...tasked with ensurance of a clear path through the debris."*

*"His duties consisted primarily of ensurance rather than active personal labor."*

"Ensurance" itself [does not appear in the dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=ensurance); is there another word which means exactly this that I could substitute?

("Supervision" comes close but does not always connote a promised outcome for which the supervisor is directly accountable.  It's the best substitute I can think of, personally, but fails to imply an actual *guarantee*.)

Comment: Why do you have to use the noun in the first place? Your question reads more like a request for proof-reading.

Comment: Did you look at the word *[assurance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assurance)*?

Comment: ensurance appears in the OED as obsolete, with quotations from the 1600s only, although is appears in Johnson's Dictionary of 1755.  M-W also lists it as obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

The action of ensuring something is simply *ensuring*, so "..your ensuring its completion would ease my mind," and "...tasked with ensuring a clear path...," and "...his duties consisted primarily of ensuring that things were accomplished rather than active personal labor" all work well this way.

Comment: I assure you, he is ensuring your insurance.

Answer (score 2):

According to Merriam-Webster, "ensurance" is a word, and I quite agree.

> [MERRIAM WEBSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ensurance): the act of means of ensuring.

Comment: Please consider linking to the reference (dictionary).